# OpenGL: How can I render a triangle mesh at 10bit (or 12bit or 16bit) channel depth color?

Tags: opengl, rendering, render, mesh, pyopengl

For a vision research experiment, I have a monitor that supports 10bit/channel (=30bit color). I want to render a triangle mesh in a simple scene that uses the full bit depth, and I want to save this rendering as a .png file. The rendering is just for single, static images, and doesn't need to happen lightning fast.

For the triangle mesh, I have:

- List of vertices in xyz coordinates
- List of triangles containing the indices of the vertices
- List of the vertex normals
- List of the triangle/face normals

My hardware includes (possibly irrelevant)

- Dell UP3218K monitor - 8k and 10bits/channel
- GeForce RTX 2080 Super (but can get a better one if needed)

I tried using the pyrender library, but it outputs the rendered scene as uint8 (limiting it to 8bit).

I can't find any code examples of OpenGL or PyOpenGL rendering meshes at 10bits or higher. With the increasing popularity of >8bit monitors, surely this is possible?

What can I use to render a mesh at 10 bit/channel depth?

**Edit with more specific question:**

I have a triangle mesh (points, vertices, normals). How can I render it (display unnecessary at this step) in a scene and save this rendering as a 10-bit depth .png file? Later, I would like to display this .png on a 10-bit monitor.

Comment: Are you trying to create a HDR context/default framebuffer or are you OK with rendering to a floating-point FBO & tone-mapping down to SDR yourself for display?

Comment: I'm inexperienced with opengl, but after looking up the default framebuffer and FBOs, I believe a FBO is more suited to what I want. I would like to take a triangle mesh and render it (display not necessary) and save it as a 10-bit/channel .png file. Later, I want to display these 10-bit .pngs on a monitor. 

I'll update the above question to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a framebuffer object (FBO) you get to decide what kind of buffer you're rendering to. Most applications would use an `GL_RGBA8` texture as the colour buffer, but you don't have to...

[Here are a list of all the formats which your graphics driver is required to support](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format#Texture_and_Renderbuffer). It may also support other ones which aren't on this list, but on this list are some formats that may be interesting to you:

- `GL_RGB10_A2` - 10 bits each for R/G/B, 2 bits for A - 32 bits per pixel
- `GL_RGBA16` - 16 bits each for R/G/B/A - 64 bits per pixel
- `GL_RGBA16F` - 16 bits each for R/G/B/A - 64 bits per pixel - but they're floating-point numbers with with 1-bit sign, 5-bit exponent and 10-bit mantissa.